# Remover mais de um item de um array

Tags: javascript, html, array

É possível remover mais de um item de um array de uma vez.

Segue o código:

```
var teste = [6,4,5];
//meu objectivo é remover os itens 4, 5 por ex

//removendo o item 4
teste.splice(1, 1)

//removendo o item 5
teste.splice(1, 2)
```

Como podem notar apos eu retirar o primeiro item o array fica 'maluco' pois tem um item a menos ou seja todos índices mudam

Comment: Já tentou `teste.splice(1, 2)`, sem rodar os outros que você já tem? O segundo parâmetro do splice é a quantidade a ser removida. [Mais na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O primeiro argumento do [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) é um índice no array, o segundo é a quantidade de itens a remover a partir dali.

Então fica assim:

```
var itens = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
var indice = 2; // lembre que começa em zero, então esta é a posição do "c"
var quantidade = 3;

var removidos = itens.splice(indice, quantidade);

console.log(itens); // ["a", "b", "f", "g"]
console.log(removidos); // ["c", "d", "e"]
```

Se não souber a posição dos itens, pode remover itens usando o método [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var itens = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];

var resultado = itens.filter(function(item) {
  return item !== 'c' &&  item !== 'e';
});

console.log(resultado); // ["a", "b", "d", "f", "g"]
```

ou assim pra ficar mais fácil:

```
var itens = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
var remover = ['f', 'c'];

var resultado = itens.filter(function(item) {
  return !~remover.indexOf(item);
});

console.log(resultado); // ["a", "b", "d", "e", "g"]
```

se quiser faça uma função pra usar outras vezes:

```
function remover(array, rem) {
  return array.filter(function(item) {
    return !~rem.indexOf(item);
  });
}

var original = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
var resultado1 = remover(original, ['f', 'c']);
var resultado2 = remover(original, ['a', 'e', 'g']);

console.log(resultado1); // ["a", "b", "d", "e", "g"]
console.log(resultado2); // ["b", "c", "d", "f"]
```

Comment: Valeu Ezequias, desconhecia essa função 'filter' do array, eu consegui realizar a tarefa usando um for e um while mas não ficou muito bonito, ficou funcional apenas. isso sem duvida vai ajudar bastante nas proximas. Valeu !

Answer (score 3):

O primeiro parâmetro é a parti de qual indice irá começar a ser removido, e o segundo quantas posições serão removidas. No meu exemplo eu estou dizendo:

*Remova 1 elemento a parti da posição 1.*

*Veja funcionando:*

```js
var fruits = [6,4,5];
    
fruits.splice(1, 1);

console.log(fruits);
```

Fonte: [W3Scholls](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)

Comment: Ola Marconi, obrigado pela resposta mas eu coloquei apenas como exemplo, ou seja nem sempre os itens a serem excluídos estarão por ultimo ou em sequência. 

Estou quase conseguindo, assim que terminar posta a resposta. Valeu!