# Remover um elemento específico com JAVASCRIPT de uma estrutura HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Olá eu não tenho muita experiência com js e estou com um problema acredito que bobo mas que há dias tento resolver e não consigo.
Eu criei uma lista de elementos HTML com a seguinte estrutura:

*HTML*

```
<ul id="NumerosAdicionados" class="fa-ul">
     <h6><strong>Numero(s) inserido(s)</strong></h6>
</ul>
```

*Função que adiciona os números*

```
var listaNumeros = [];
function adicionaNumeros() {
    var i = listaNumeros.length;
    listaNumeros.push(i);
    $("#NumerosAdicionados").append("<li id=" + i + "   value=" + i + "><i class='fa fa-times-circle' onclick=excluiNumero(" + i + ")></i>" + i + "</li>");

}
```

*Função que exclui os números*

```
function excluiNumero(indice) {
    listaProcessos.splice(indice, 1);
}
```

Com esse código ele remove o elemento da lista, mas não remove do HTML, apenas quando seleciono o primeiro elemento para excluir ele exclui todos do HTML.

Comment: O que é `listaProcessos`?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Remover mais de um item de um array](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50520/remover-mais-de-um-item-de-um-array)

Comment: @Randrade, o problema apresentado pela AP está relacionado a modificação dinâmica no HTML, e ela já consegue excluir o item array. Acho que essa questão, apesar de ser bem parecida, não menciona isso, mas posso estar errado.

Comment: @SamirBraga Se a dúvida do AP for essa mesmo, você tem razão. Eu havia entendido que era algo em relação ao `.splice()`.

Comment: A minha dúvida não era com relação ao splice não, era como exibir mesmo o html depois do item exluído.

Comment: E queres atribuir novos numeros ou pode ficar 1,2,5,6 no caso de teres excluído o 3 e 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se `listaProcessos` for o mesmo que `listaNumeros`, você pode fazer assim:

Criei uma função `renderList()` que recria a lista baseada no array `listaNumeros` e em seus valores.

```
function renderList(){
    // Deixa dentro da ul só que tinha antes
    $("#NumerosAdicionados").html('<h3><strong>Numero(s) inserido(s)</strong></h3>');
    var html = ""; // var que receberá o html completo das li
    listaNumeros.forEach(function(el, i){
        // a cada item do array adicionar um novo li
        html += "<li id=" + el + "   value=" + el + "><i class='fa fa-times-circle' onclick=excluiNumero(" + el + ")></i>" + el + "</li>";
    }) 
    // faz apenas um append (melhor para o desempenho)
    $("#NumerosAdicionados").append(html);
}
```

Basta adicioná-la a função de excluir:

```
function excluiNumero(indice) {
    listaNumeros.splice(indice, 1);
    renderList();
}
```

Você vai ter um pouco de problemas ao adicionar número na sequência, já que sua função se baseia na quantidade de elementos e essa quantidade será mudada ao excluir. O que você pode fazer é somar ao último elemento, mas imagino que isso seja apenas um exemplo.

#### Resultado:

```js
var listaNumeros = [];
function adicionaNumeros() {
    var i = listaNumeros.length == 0 ? listaNumeros.length : +listaNumeros[listaNumeros.length-1]+1;
    listaNumeros.push(i);
    $("#NumerosAdicionados").append("<li id=" + i + "   value=" + i + "><i class='fa fa-times-circle' onclick=excluiNumero(" + i + ")></i>" + i + "</li>");
}
$('.inserir').click(adicionaNumeros)

function excluiNumero(indice) {
    listaNumeros.splice(indice, 1);
   renderList();
}
function renderList(){
 $("#NumerosAdicionados").html('<h3><strong>Numero(s) inserido(s)</strong></h3>');
 var html = "";
 listaNumeros.forEach(function(el, i){
  html += "<li id=" + el + "   value=" + el + "><i class='fa fa-times-circle' onclick=excluiNumero(" + el + ")></i>" + el + "</li>";
 }) 
  $("#NumerosAdicionados").append(html);
}
$('.excluir').click(function(){
 excluiNumero(1);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="NumerosAdicionados" class="fa-ul">
     <h3><strong>Numero(s) inserido(s)</strong></h3>
</ul>

<button class="inserir">Inserir</button>

<button class="excluir">Excluir o 2°</button>
```

Comment: Muito obrigada, Samir Braga!!! Era exatamente isso que eu precisava mas não sabia como fazer.